# How to convert MSB - LSB Format handling in PHP

Tags: php

I want to convert MSB to LSB.

```
Input Data = 764491139 (MSB) , Correct result = 2201325869 (LSB)
```

My coding :

```
$value = "764491139";
echo bindec(strrev(decbin($value))); //Convert to LSB
Result : 812327533; //Correct is 2201325869
```

but result is incorrect.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

A simple search in Google founds this snippet from the PHP manual

```
    function uInt64($i, $endianness=false) {
        $f = is_int($i) ? "pack" : "unpack";

        if ($endianness === true) {  // big-endian
            $i = $f("J", $i);
        }
        else if ($endianness === false) {  // little-endian
            $i = $f("P", $i);
        }
        else if ($endianness === null) {  // machine byte order
            $i = $f("Q", $i);
        }

        return is_array($i) ? $i[1] : $i;
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php#119403

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 5 years later but I whipped up a function to do what you asked. It works with 32-bit integers.

```php
function endianflip($input) {
  for($r=$i=0;$i<32;$i+=8)
    $r|= ($input>>24-$i&0xFF)<<$i;
  return $r;
}

echo endianflip(764491139).PHP_EOL; // 2201325869
echo endianflip(2201325869);        // 764491139
```